# How to disable default notification in urban airship + android

Tags: android

I working on android with urban airship.
I got issues like I custom one notification, when I push message, it will show two notifications include "Message" like image and one custom notification.

Could you help me resolve that issues?
Thanks!

Link image: [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEx7n.png)

Comment: I found that way to resolve that issuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that way to resolve that issues.
To disable Urban Airship's notifications, override BasicPushNotificationBuilder:

```
BasicPushNotificationBuilder nb = new BasicPushNotificationBuilder() {
    @Override
    public Notification buildNotification(String alert,
            Map<String, String> extras) {
        return null;
    }
};
// Disable notifications
PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
```

For more information: http://www.techques.com/question/1-9063960/How-to-change-the-status-bar-icon-based-on-extra-value-from-Urban-Airship-Pushnotification-in-Android